# SQL row for each Date beween two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 18 and I am trying to return a row for each date between two dates. This is a bed census report with the following requirements.

All patients who are in that bed at midnight 23:59. If a person was admitted 2016-07-08 and discharged 2016-07-11 this will have 3 rows. Outputting something like this

```
Epidsode date ,admitted date, discharged date, Ward
2016-07-08  2016-07-08   2016-07-11  Ward a
2016-07-09  2016-07-08   2016-07-11  Ward a
2016-07-10  2016-07-08   2016-07-11  Ward b
```

Also if someone was admitted and discharged in the same day then this will show one row.

Is this something like this possible to do?

I have tried searching other topics but cannot find exact help
Any help would be great

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select admitted_date as episode_date, admitted_date, discharge_date, ward
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, episode_date), admitted_date, discharge_date, ward
      from cte
       where episode_date < dateadd(day, -1, discharge_date)
    )
select *
from cte
with option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Note:  If there are ever more than 100 days, you will need `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=835464d2c2bd67eec32e6f8a00bf7bde) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi Gordan, I have tried your code but still not working as I would like. Its possible that some stays could be over a 100 days. I am also going to need to join other tables. But if I just get the basic information right I can build it up. I noticed you aliased the first column. Its saying invalid column then we try to use the alias further down if that makes sense.

Comment: @Conger88 . . . The recursive CTE was not very recursive.  I fixed the answer.  It also had an off-by-one error.

Comment: This looks absolutely great. The fiddle works exactly like I need. I just need to join multiple other tables and filters now. Let me play around with it and I might come back to you on it if thats ok. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff I am still having some trouble with this and not outputting exactly as I want, I am getting the Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: @Conger88 . . . As specified in the answer (even before I edited it), you need `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Comment: I didnt know where to add it. also it works when I remove the 'with' so just option (maxrecursion 0). I need to play around with it more but looks better now.